# Rename dates files with R

Tags: r, file, date, rename

I have named each file for each day of the years between 2012 and 2016 like this: 2012-01-01.csv; 2012-01-02.csv... until 2016-12-31.csv. But for 2017 and 2018 the files are named like this: 20170101.csv; 20170102.csv... Could someone help me include the hyphens in the second files so that they have the same name as the first ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: use this instead**

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\...Path to your data")

DataFileNames <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")
sub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.*)","\\1-\\2-\\3\\4",DataFileNames)
file.rename(DataFileNames,NewDataFileNames)
```

---

Old answer:

> Theres a lot of missing information from your question, but you should
>   be able to adjust the code below to suit your needs.Mostly, you'll
>   need to edit the read.csv line if you have headers and adjust other
>   parameters.
>
> **Note:** This will overwrite all your tables, so make sure the data is imported properly with the `read.csv` in the `lapply` before you
>   run the `write.csv` (last line)
>
> ```
> setwd("C:\\Users\\...Path to your data")
>
> DataFileNames <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")
> Datafiles <- lapply(DataFileNames, read.csv, header=FALSE)
>
> DataFileNames <- sub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).csv","\\1-\\2-\\3",DataFileNames)
> lapply(1:length(Datafiles), function(x) write.csv(Datafiles[x], DataFileNames[x]))
> ```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! It was usefull and the names changed, but the files are not .csv now. Im working with MacOS and now the files appears as exec files.

Comment: @AlejandroBernal the `list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")` is just looking for files with the extension `.csv` you can change it to `.exec` if you'd like as I have in my answer. you can even just use `list.files()` to get all files in the folder. I have edited the `gsub` line to make sure it uses the same extensions that the files already have.

Comment: I mean, the files are originally .csv, and I want to keep them as .csv so I can work with them later, but when I apply your code they have changed to exec.

Comment: It appears that before my edit I forgot to include the `.csv` extension in the rename. If your there are no other files in your folder you can use the same code as above to fix this issues. by getting all files in the folder `DataFileNames <- list.files()` then using `NewDataFileNames <- sub("(.*)","\\1.csv",DataFileNames)` to add the `csv` extension and finally renaming them with `file.rename(DataFileNames,NewDataFileNames)`. Sorry about that mistake.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you. And again, sorry for the mixup, but we fixed it in the end ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code with `list.files` + `file.rename`

```
old <- list.files(pattern = ".*.csv")
new <- paste0(as.Date(gsub(".csv","",old,fixed = TRUE),format = c("%Y-%m-%d","%Y%m%d")),".csv")
file.rename(old,new)
```